# Android dialog being "leaked window "

Tags: android, dialog

I have been stucked by the following when showing a dialog to confirm closing the app. The app can be closed properly, yet in the logcat whole page is red. I have researched through the web and some says the dialog should be created being showing.

### Code:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() 
    {
        final Dialog dialog1 = new Dialog(First.this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);


        dialog1.setContentView(R.layout.alert_dialog_quit_with_email);
        dialog1.setCancelable(true);
        dialog1.show();  // LINE 323

        TextView thankyou = (TextView) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.thankyou);
        TextView Title_V1 = (TextView) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.Title_V1);
        Button alert_cancel = (Button) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.button_cancel);
        Button alert_quit = (Button) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.button_ok);
        Button button_email = (Button) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.button_emailll);

alert_cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                dialog1.dismiss();
                return;
            }
        });

        alert_quit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                First.this.finish();
            }
        });

        button_email.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                View view1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.first, null);
                button_Email_click(view1);
            }
        });
    }
```

### logcat:

```
09-29 23:33:45.450: E/WindowManager(27052): Activity com.abc.abc.First has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@42cc5de0 that was originally added here
09-29 23:33:45.450: E/WindowManager(27052): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.abc.abc.First has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@42cc5de0 that was originally added here
09-29 23:33:45.450: E/WindowManager(27052):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:412)
09-29 23:33:45.450: E/WindowManager(27052):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:312)
09-29 23:33:45.450: E/WindowManager(27052):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
09-29 23:33:45.450: E/WindowManager(27052):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
09-29 23:33:45.450: E/WindowManager(27052):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:554)
09-29 23:33:45.450: E/WindowManager(27052):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
09-29 23:33:45.450: E/WindowManager(27052):     at com.abc.abc.First.onBackPressed(First.java:323)
09-29 23:33:45.450: E/WindowManager(27052):     at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2192)
09-29 23:33:45.450: E/WindowManager(27052):     at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2729)
09-29 23:33:45.450: E/WindowManager(27052):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2431)
09-29 23:33:45.450: E/WindowManager(27052):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2009)
09-29 23:33:45.450: E/WindowManager(27052):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3942)
09-29 23:33:45.450: E/WindowManager(27052):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleImeFinishedEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3890)
09-29 23:33:45.450: E/WindowManager(27052):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3019)
09-29 23:33:45.450: E/WindowManager(27052):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-29 23:33:45.450: E/WindowManager(27052):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-29 23:33:45.450: E/WindowManager(27052):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
09-29 23:33:45.450: E/WindowManager(27052):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-29 23:33:45.450: E/WindowManager(27052):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-29 23:33:45.450: E/WindowManager(27052):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
09-29 23:33:45.450: E/WindowManager(27052):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
09-29 23:33:45.450: E/WindowManager(27052):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

### Question:

I have tried to write as `dialog1.create().show();` but it then underlines in red for the `.create()` and describes it as `The method create() is undefined for the type Dialog`.

I discovered that the red logcat will only appear when press the quit button...is it because it is going to show a dialog but the activity is closed? I I have already declared dialog1...how can this be modified? Thanks!

Comment: Please reconsider.  Mobile apps should not show "are you sure you want to exit" dialogs.  It makes no sense in Android.  When I click back on this webpage, it doesn't ask me to confirm or ask if I want to close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dismiss your dialog in both methods as well, like this

```
 alert_quit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {

                  First.this.finish();
                  dialog1.dismiss();

            }
        });

        button_email.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                View view1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.first, null);
                button_Email_click(view1);
                dialog1.dismiss();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your should add `View.` to your `onClickListeners`, and `Override` them.

ex.

```
alert_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                dialog1.dismiss();
                return;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try same inside onKeyDown instead of onBackPressed.

```
       @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                // Your code
            }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `dialog1.cancel()` also. Basically the problem could be since the dialog is not cancelled or dismissed, it leaks.